# Using Joomla to Display Products

Tags: php, joomla

My question might be a stupid questions. But need to get help from experts. I have worked with Magento, so by using Magento we can simply handle this work. But we got a new project recently and unfortunately they are demanding to develop the system using Joomla where they need to add products and need to display in their web site. They do not need to handle cart and payment related stuffs but they need to handle the products dynamically.

My bad luck I have been allocated to this development and stuck with how can do it in a easy way since this is first time I am going to work with Joomla. Welcome all the ideas. I tried to find some solution in internet but I could not get any:(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Virtuemart](http://virtuemart.net/), the Joomla Component as a catalogue, it has a templating system just like Magento. Everything can be a challenge to learn, but I actually see Magento more difficult to grasp than Virtuemart.

[The Forum](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?PHPSESSID=0019be890c5ca34f2c1cf54ae830dca8&board=130.0) is okay, if a little lack luster.

Comment: I really need to thank you.. You gave me a very simple solution for the problem. It works like charm.. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Remember, Joomla works with template overwrides! Everything should be 99.999% in your theme folder :)

Answer (score 1):

I have always used [JoomShopping](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/shopping-cart/5378) as I find the backend much more simple than the like of [VirtueMart](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/shopping-cart/129). However VirtueMart might be more suitable for your needs. You might also be interested in [HikaShop](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/shopping-cart/14275) or [redShop](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/shopping-cart/11571).

Each have their advantages and disadvantages so it might be worth testing each one to see which you prefer.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for this information... I will check these things also.. :)